# Show that $\Bbb Q^n \cup (\Bbb R-\Bbb Q)^n$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have difficulty with this problem and I have not idea to show this. How can I show that  $\Bbb Q^n \cup (\Bbb R-\Bbb Q)^n$ is connected? If $n=1$ it's obvious because the sum is $\Bbb R$
is connected. But in general?

Comment: In general the sum is $\mathbb R^n$ that is also connected, or i'm missing something?

Comment: @GiuseppeBargagnati you are missing something. E.g. $(2,\sqrt 2) \notin$ it for $n=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $E = \mathbb Q^n \cup (\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q)^n.$ For $x\in \mathbb R^n,$ let $L(x) = \{tx: t\in \mathbb R\}.$ ($L(x)$ is the line in $\mathbb R^n$ through the origin and $x.$) Verify that if $q = (q_1,\dots ,q_n)\in \mathbb  Q^n$ and each $q_k \ne 0,$ then $L(q)\subset E.$ Consider the union of all of such lines.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: @DomenicoVuono Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Yes.. thanks but someone has downvote(why?)

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: @zhw. Do you claim that this union of lines equals $E$?

Answer (score 0):

All points from $\mathbb{Q}^n$ lay in one linear connectivity component. (Full line from $P_1$ to $P_2$ lays in your set, if $P_1$ and $P_2$ have no equals coordinates.  Anyway, you can use rational point $P_3$ ).

So, to the contrary: 
Your set is union of open-close $X$ and $Y$. 
Let $P_1$ - rational point in $X$,  $P_2$ - rational point in $Y$. 
QED.