# Find all path connected components of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Let us define $\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$.
Find all path-connected components of $\mathbb{P}^n\cup\mathbb{Q}^n$

I tried solving this question but I'm out of luck. Any help, please?

It is not a duplicate of [Connectedness of points with both rational or irrational coordinates in the plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135660/connectedness-of-points-with-both-rational-or-irrational-coordinates-in-the-plan) because they prove connectivity of the set and not path-connectivity.

In the paragraph above there is an explanation of why this is NOT a duplicate of an existing post, please look closely at the questions asked...

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What approach(es) have you tried?

Comment: @Brahadeesh I was able to show that all points in the form $r∗(q_1,...q_n)$ where $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $q_1,...q_n$ are rational, are path connected

Comment: @ShaharRomemPeled You can say slightly more. From the answer to the linked question, you can deduce that for every $\mathbf{q} = (q_1,\dots,q_n) \in \mathbb{Q}^n$ and every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ the points $(q_1 \pm t,\dots, q_n \pm t)$ are path-connected to $\mathbf{q}$ for every choice of sign in each coordinate.

Comment: Since any two points in $\mathbb{Q}^n$ can be joined by "diagonal" line segments, it follows that $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is contained in a path-component.

Comment: @Brahadeesh yes but what about others points?

Comment: I’m not sure, still thinking over it :) I will comment/answer if and when I solve it.

Comment: I had updated my answer with a complete solution, but forgotten to ping you. Do check it, please :)

Comment: @Brahadeesh Thank you for the complete solution!! Really helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The second half of this answer is based on @RobertIsrael's comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135685/279515).*

---

Let $\mathbf{q} = (q_1,\dots,q_n) \in \mathbb{Q}^n$. For every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that
$$
(q_1 \pm t, \dots, q_n \pm t) \in \mathbb{P}^n \cup \mathbb{Q}^n
$$
for every choice of sign in each coordinate. This is because if $t \in \mathbb{Q}$, then the above element lies in $\mathbb{Q}^n$ and if $t \in \mathbb{P}$ then the above element lies in $\mathbb{P^n}$. Any two elements in $\mathbb{Q}^n$ can be connected by means of such straight-line paths. Hence, $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is contained in a path-connected component.

Next, let $\mathbf{r} = (r_1,\dots,r_n) \in \mathbb{P}^n$. There is a sequence $\mathbf{q}_j = (q_{1j},\dots,q_{nj}) \in \mathbb{Q}^n$ such that $\lim_{j \to \infty} \mathbf{q}_j = \mathbf{r}$, that is, $\lim_{j \to \infty} q_{ij} = r_i$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$. By the previous discussion, there is a path in $\mathbb{P^n} \cup \mathbb{Q}^n$ connecting $\mathbf{q}_j$ to $\mathbf{q}_{j+1}$ for each $j \in \mathbb{N}$. By concatenating these paths, we get a path in $\mathbb{P}^n \cup \mathbb{Q}^n$ connecting $\mathbf{q}_1 \in \mathbb{Q}^n$ with $\mathbf{r} \in \mathbb{P}^n$. This shows that $\mathbb{P}^n$ is contained in the same path-connected component as $\mathbb{Q}^n$.

Thus, $\mathbb{P}^n \cup \mathbb{Q}^n$ is path-connected.